migrating out servers while users have A records pointing to the current server
I just bought a small company and they use a hosting provider that basically just massively upmarks AWS's prices. They use AWS RDS databases, and ec2 servers.
i want to save costs and move over to AWS to cut them out. However, I have one issue.
the company is a landing page builder, and people build their websites in our app. For their sites to have a custom domain, they need to have an A record pointed to our servers IP address.
It will not be a good thing to ask every user to change their DNS.
i've done some research that a reverse proxy or DNS failover solution could handle this.
but I wanted to reach out to see if there are any issues with this approach?
for example,
before migration:
proxy setup on a new server:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yourapp.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://1.234.567.890;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

after migration:
proxy setup after the servers are completely setup.
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name yourapp.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://3.456.789.012;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

what I am trying to achieve is users A records are always pointing to 1.234.567.890, they don't need to do anything at all, however it gets forwarded to the new server I get setup at 3.456.789.012
i have not tried anything yet.

Although you made it clear that you don't want to reach your customers and ask them to update their records, I think it would be better to use your proxy solution as only a stopgap, ask the customers to migrate from A to CNAME giving them enough time to do that, and finally remove the proxy. Imagine that you'll need to migrate to yet another IP, this makes your proxy solution virtually permanent. On the other hand, with CNAME you need to update A/AAAA records on your side only.
